# Firebase Cloud Messages,messages takes time to be delivered even though the app is in the foreground

Tags: android, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have configured my application server to communicate with FCM through XMPP. I maintain a XMPP connection that is always online. The configuration looks fine and I can successfully send XMPP messages to the FCM (I'm saying this on the basis of the ACK message received by my server).

On the Android client side I have implemented the `FirebaseMessagingService` to receive the messages. The problem I'm facing is that, the messages are not received instantaneously when the app is in the foreground, its actually quite inconsistent as in it works fine sometimes but sometimes messages get bundled up and received at once after some delay. My use-case requires the messages to reach the client immediately in case the app is in the foreground. Can you please tell me if I'm missing something. The XMPP message i send and the response are given below.

**Sent XMPP message:**

```
<message id="">
    <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
        {"to":"<registration-id>","priority" : "high","message_id":"m-1471190678140"}
    </gcm> 
</message>
```

**Received ACK message:**

```
<message>
    <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
        {"message_type":"ack","from":"<registration-id>","message_id":"m-1471190678126"}
    </gcm> 
</message>
```

**Edit**
On further investigation I noticed that the messages stop after the app is left idle for a few minutes and are received after about a minute of the app becoming active,but, if i toggle the internet(wi-fi) its starts working as expected again.It seems like the connection between the android client and the FCM gets timed out.I found documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime) where it states that **"When a connection is established, FCM delivers all pending messages to the device"** .Is there a way to manually establish a connection between the android client and the FCM when the app comes online so the it's always open when I need it?

Comment: There may be network conditions between your receiving device and FCM that is causing the delay. I don't think you are doing anything wrong given that you are eventually receiving them. I'd try with an emulator on a machine with a good connection and see if the results are the same.

Comment: Hey Arthur,thanks for your response,I've added a few more details to my query,do let me know if you have any pointers to let me know how to move forward,cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I, today encountered the same problem. After so much digging, I came across Arthur's response above, and then it occurred to me that I started experiencing the problem after switch from WIFI  to the phone's mobile internet. I then switched back to WIFI, and message delivery became instant.

So in summary, connect your phones to a WIFI network and you will be OK. It doesn't matter if it's another phone's tethered hotspot.

I am yet to find out why Firebase Messaging Service behaves this way, but would do that once I am done with the task at hand